# putting external files in eclipse relatively

Tags: java, eclipse

i have src folder and inside it there are many packages, one of which is hibernate.util.

earlier i had placed hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder and gave its absolute path and now since i have to deploy this app , the absolute path is giving me problems.

i tried adding a new resource folder as source folder, included it in source folder , added it to classpath but everytime its gives file not found

i am using eclipse IDE

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet sandbox
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2216)
    at dal.utils.HibernateUtils.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:25)
    at dal.utils.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:19)
    at dal.service.CalcDataMapper.load(CalcDataMapper.java:17)
    at com.renturduniya.www.sandbox.init(sandbox.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you plz share how you are giving the relative path?

Comment: @Patton i am giving resourceFiles/hibernate.cfg.xml in file name and resourceFiles is a new folder in app root, i am using web project of eclpise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass it a File. A File represents a path on the file system. Your config file should be bundled in the jar/war along with the classes of your app, and be loaded using the class loader.

You should use the [method taking a URL as argument](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#configure%28java.net.URL%29) instead, and pass it the URL returned by

```
SomeClassOfYourWebApp.class.getResource(
    "/the/package/where/the/file/is/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: please elaborate i cant understand this, you mean i should create a new package say "resourceFiles" and put this config file there and call this in 'HibernateUtils.java' as HibernateUtils.class.getResource("resourceFiles/hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: Yes, execept the path should start with a `/`, and that you're not forced to create a dedicated package.

Comment: by not creating a dedicated package you mean i can place this in src sub folder use HibernateUtils.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: Yes, except the path must start with a `/`. You can put the file in the root package, or in any other package, as long as the path used to load the file matches with the package where the file is stored. Why don't you read the javadoc of `Class.getResource()`?

Comment: haha, sorry i have been struggling with this stupid problem since the starting of my project 1 month ago, earlier i just hardcoded absolute path but now at deploy time its eating me, and i am searching something since morning and you came closes, let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slash like `/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` in case you have hardcoded the value in the hibernateUtil class. If not try doing some thing like this

```
    URL url = hibernateUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
                    "hibernate.cfg.xml");
   // Now try to get the get path of the file using 
    url.getPath();
```

I think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

External files always are absolute path.

Comment: if they're into your Working directory, they aren't external files

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use the classloader.

```
Whatever.class.getClassLoader().getResource("name");
```

As this will actually take the classpath into account.

Otherwise, a relative path name will be relative to your *working directory*, not to your *source tree*.

Note that in *Eclipse*, *Run Configurations* you have in the *Arguments* tab a setting called **Working directory**, which defaults to your project folder. For multiple run configurations you can use different working folders (and this way, different configurations for your application).

A common directory layout might be:

```
bin/     compiled classes, in classpath
src/     source files, not used at runtime
site1/   configuration for running site 1
site2/   configuration for running site 2
```

and then having the files in:

```
site1/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
site2/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

and setting the **working folder** to `site1` or `site2`.